# Change of value label according to change of star rating view in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am making a screen giving a movie star rating. I am creating a view with 1 to 10 points below 5 stars. I would like to make an integer rise by one for every half of a star.

I'm using Cosmos view. The problem is that the integer is incremented by one when the star is full, not by 1 every time the star is filled in half.

```
import UIKit

class CommentsViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var rateView: CosmosView!
    @IBOutlet weak var rateLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        rateView.settings.fillMode = .half

        rateView.didTouchCosmos = didTouchCosmos
    }

    private class func formatValue(_ value: Double) -> Int {
        return Int(value)
    }

    private func didTouchCosmos(_ rating: Double) {
        rateLabel.text = "\(CommentsViewController.formatValue(rating))"

    }
}
```

When using the cosmos view, can I change the code so that the integer is incremented by 1 each time the star is filled in half?

Comment: Where is the `rating` value set?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just multiply the rating by 2?

```
private class func formatValue(_ value: Double) -> Int {
    return Int(value) * 2
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. !!@Xcoder
But
```
return Int (value) * 2
```
The code doubles the value when a star is filled, but when the star is half filled, the number does not rise.